# Pandas looking up values

Tags: python, pandas, lookup

I have the following df:

```
Id  Date    Value
111 1/1/18  a
111 1/3/18  a
111 1/5/18  x 
222 1/1/18  x
222 1/2/18  y
333 1/2/18  a
333 1/3/18  x
333 1/4/18  a
333 1/5/18  a
444 1/5/18  y
555 1/2/18  a
```

I want to add 2 new columns according to the date where the Value field contains the letter "a".

result:

```
Id  Value  StartDate  EndDate
111 a      1/1/18     1/3/18
222                              (this id does not contain a)
333 a      1/4/18     1/5/18     (take the latest date contain a)
444                              (this id does not contain a)
555 a      1/2/18                (there's no ending date)
```

Thank you :)

Comment: you need to uniquely identify your rows. Say value = a AND id = 111. can you do that?

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ I would group the Id together but for the "Value" I'm not sure how to approach that.

Comment: What is in your sample , id 333 they have three value

Comment: @Wen for 333, we count 1/4/18 as StartDate and ignore 1/2/18 since the value was switched after that.  Basically, we only count the most recent Date.

Comment: @TylerNG adding a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need rename the column to what you need

```
df=df.groupby(['Value','Id']).tail(2)    
df1=df.set_index(['Value','Id'])
df1.set_index(df1.groupby(['Id','Value']).cumcount(),append=True).Date.unstack().unstack().stack(dropna=False)
Out[914]: 
                0       1
Value Id                 
a     111  1/1/18  1/3/18
      222    None    None
      333  1/4/18  1/5/18
      444    None    None
      555  1/2/18    None
x     111  1/5/18    None
      222  1/1/18    None
      333  1/3/18    None
      444    None    None
      555    None    None
y     111    None    None
      222  1/2/18    None
      333    None    None
      444  1/5/18    None
      555    None    None
```

Answer (score 2):

you can easily do something like

```
df.loc[(df.Value== 'a') & (df.Id == 111), 'StartDate'] = '1/1/18'
```

and so on and so forth

Comment: this would be inefficient because if there are more than 1000 Ids, it will be very tedious

Comment: you can loop. somehow you have to tell Pandas which Ids you want

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @Wen's,

```
df['new'] = df[df['Value'] == 'a'].groupby('Id').Date.tail(2)
df['new']=df.dropna().groupby('Id')['new'].cumcount()
new_df = df.dropna().pivot('Id', 'new' , 'Date').rename(columns={0.0:'Start Date', 1.0: 'End Date'})


new Start Date  End Date
Id      
111 1/1/18      1/3/18
333 1/4/18      1/5/18
555 1/2/18      None
```

Edit: With two extra rows in Id 555

```
    Id  Date    Value
0   111 1/1/18  a
1   111 1/3/18  a
2   111 1/5/18  x
3   222 1/1/18  x
4   222 1/2/18  y
5   333 1/2/18  a
6   333 1/3/18  x
7   333 1/4/18  a
8   333 1/5/18  a
9   444 1/5/18  y
10  555 1/2/18  a
11  555 1/3/18  a
12  555 1/4/18  a
```

The above solution will return

```
new Start Date  End Date
Id      
111 1/1/18      1/3/18
333 1/4/18      1/5/18
555 1/3/18      1/4/18
```

Comment: this works great but the only problem I have is that: 
if Id 555 has 2 more rows "555 1/3/18  a" and "555 1/4/18  a" then the end date would be 1/3/18 when it should be 1/4/18 since it takes in the next consecutive day.  Is there a way to work around that?

Comment: If id 555 has two more rows, then the start date would be 1/3/18 and end data 1/4/18 as we are using tail(2) to select the two latest rows. That's what you have mentioned in the comment. Do you want different behavior?

Comment: Thanks! However for Id 555, the Start Date should be 1/2/18 since "a" was first placed in 1/2/18 and continued to "a" to 1/4/18.  Sorry i wasn't clear in the question.